# How can I add a property calculated by a JavaScript extension with C#?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array and want access by property (not function) like:

```
let arr = [1,2,3];
console.log("last element: ", arr.last)
```

I try like it, but got error:

```
Array.prototype.last = (() => {
    return this[this.length - 1];
})();
```

Update 1:
yes i know how do it like extend method:

```
 Array.prototype.mysort = function() {
        this.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
        return this;
    }
    myarray.mysort();
```

but how do it like property?

```
myarray.mysort;
```

Comment: Don't use an arrow function if you want to use `this`. Use a traditional function.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: @Barmar because i come from C# and cant find how in js prototype like property (not call like function)

Comment: I think you meant to write "like in C#".

Comment: Anyway, just change `() =>` to `function()`

Comment: Also remove the `()` at the end. That calls the function immediately, instead of storing the function.

Comment: Look up JavaScript "getters".

Comment: if i change to function()  i will call extension like method . Questiong about how call like property.    Okay I'll take a look about getters

Comment: I attempted to make sense of your post title and format it as a proper sentence. Please revise further if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). You need to use `Object.defineProperty()` to add a getter to an existing object, in this case the `Array.prototype` object.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "last", {
  get: function() {
    return this[this.length - 1];
  }
});

const a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a.last);
```